Sony Camera Remote SDK Connect() function does not return a device handle
I'm currently working on a project using the Sony Camera Remote SDK (v1.12.00) and I cannot get the connect function to return a device handle no matter what I do. I've tried re-downloading and rebuilding the SDK to make sure the SDK is good.
When I print the device handle after connecting all I get is "0" or (NULL) which means it hasn't changed from when it was declared.
It's also important to mention that the SDK is initializing and creating a USB object for my camera, just not going through with the connection process.
Here is the code I'm working on:
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include "CRSDK/CameraRemote_SDK.h"
#include "CameraDevice.h"
#include "Text.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;


using namespace SCRSDK;


class MyDeviceCallback : public IDeviceCallback {
    void OnConnected(DeviceConnectionVersioin version) {
        DeviceConnectionVersioin ver = version;
        // Program can use the device handle. 
    }
};


int main() {



    CrCameraDeviceModelList usbModel = CrCameraDeviceModelList::CrCameraDeviceModel_ILX_LR1;

    ICrCameraObjectInfo* pCam = nullptr;

    CrChar serialNum[(SCRSDK::USB_SERIAL_LENGTH + 1)] = { 0 }; // +1 is Null-terminate
    memcpy(serialNum, L"D516000F44E5", sizeof(serialNum)); // wide char on Windows

    CrError err = CreateCameraObjectInfoUSBConnection(&pCam, usbModel, (unsigned char*)serialNum);

    MyDeviceCallback* cb = new MyDeviceCallback();

    CrDeviceHandle hDev = NULL;

    /*camera->connect(CrSdkControlMode_Remote, CrReconnecting_ON);*/
    Connect(pCam, cb, &hDev, CrSdkControlMode_Remote, CrReconnecting_ON, 0, 0, 0, 0U);


    std::cout << hDev << " : Device Handle" << std::endl;
    std::cout << err << std::endl;

    SendCommand(hDev, CrCommandId::CrCommandId_Release, CrCommandParam_Down);

    // Wait, then send shutter up
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(35ms);

    SendCommand(hDev, CrCommandId::CrCommandId_Release, CrCommandParam_Up);


}


I've also made sure the linker has the .lib files and that it can see the dll's and that the headers are seen.

Connect() returns a CrError, just as CreateCameraObjectInfoUSBConnection() does. What values are they both returning? You are printing out only the 1st one.

They are both returning CrError_None or 0. Also I apologize, I should have been more clear in my question, I can't get the Connect() function to do anything with hDev. hDev stays null even after the Connect() function call and the function should be changing it.

Then you should contact the SDK author for help. The code you provided looks fine, based on a few examples I could find (aside from the lack of error checking).

After a bit of back and forth with Sony, we found a solution.
The SCRSDK::CreateCameraInfoUSBConnection() method is broken and will be removed in the next release of the SDK.
Although it appeared the SCRSDK::Connect() method was the problem. It was SCRSDK::CreateCameraInfoUSBConnection() because it was throwing no errors and my variable pCam did have some data in it.
From now on use ICrEnumCameraObjectInfo::GetCameraObjectInfo() to generate device data.
